# Shortcut to move window away to other workspace (stay focused on current workspace)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, workspaces

Is there a way to create a keyboard shortcut for moving a window away to another workspace and remaining focused on the current workspace (so not the default behavior of "move window one workspace down" etc)?

(Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

Comment: Related - https://askubuntu.com/questions/98872/move-window-to-right-left-workspace-shortcut.

Comment: Also this - https://www.howtogeek.com/113330/how-to-master-ubuntus-unity-desktop-8-things-you-need-to-know/.  So we're clear - this Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Arrow Key does what you want, but it takes the focus to the new workspace, you want it to remain on the current workspace, correct?

Comment: @slm, exactly, I want the focus to remain with the workspace I was looking at. I want to have this as a way to move away a window to another workspace when I stop using it for the moment (but I might want to get it back quickly later so I don't want to close it.) I want to "slide it" to a workspace I'm not looking at right now. As far as I can tell, your answer just points me to the "move window one workspace down" hotkey (which by default is the key combination you describe).

Comment: I have asked a related question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1216679/how-can-i-send-a-window-to-a-different-workspace-without-changing-the-active-wor) which got a useful answer

Answer (score 1):

According to the 18.04 Ubuntu documentation titled: [Move a window to a different workspace](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-workspaces-movewindow.html.en):

- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd>
- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd>

Comment: As said under [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1216679/925128), these shortcuts do not keep the focus on the current workspace, but move it to the one to which the window was sent. According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1216683/925128) answer, a such short-key is missing in gnome.